# My Samsung Galaxy S 2 indicates it is charging but doesn't

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery, charging

My Samsung Galaxy S 2 indicates charging but is not adding charge to the battery. I have changed my charger many times but the problem continues. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your micro-USB connector i.e the place where you connect the charger to the phone. Some times the pins present there bend out of place and so this can happen.

Take your phone for a repair.